# No Style on Error Document (Server)

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, server

My page runs on a local server, using Apache 2.4 (I still can't access my server from outside).

I configured Apache to have an "Auth" before gaining access to my page (using `.htaccess`).

Now, here's the problem, when the server denies a user access (such as wrong password / user), it serves the 400 Page, but without the style.

Here's my server:

```
─ htdocs/
     ║
     ╠═ Error400.html
     ║
     ╚═ css/
         ║
         ╠═ Stylesheet.css
```

*Should I just put the style on the HTML Page (using `<style>`)?*

Answer (score 2):

**Use absolute links in error pages.**
If you use any graphics or links in an error page, don't use "relative links". Instead, make all your links "absolute links" that start with `http://www.example.com/...`.

Or a root-relative link, beginning the href value with `/`.

In your case: `http://www.example.com/css/Stylesheet.css` or `/css/Stylesheet.css`;